# can't launch spyder from terminal ubuntu 16.04

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

For some reason spyder can't launch on my linux machine (running ubuntu 16.04) via the terminal.
When I type spyder in a terminal it says that spyder is not installed.
However I am able to launch spyder via the graphical interface. please I am trying to figure out what's the problem.
on my personal directory I have two folders: .spyder2 and other called .spyder2-py3

Comment: Did you use `spyder3` instead of `spyder`? That's the name of the executable when you install Spyder in Ubuntu for Python 3.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos Cordoba, yes, it is `spyder3` instead of `spyder` command , However, I used it this way: `sudo spyder3 &`

Comment: Why did you that? There's no need to run Spyder as root.

Comment: No clue what did I do during the installation process; for some reason this command has an administrative privilege. here is what `ls -l`  command gives:  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67 févr. 16  2016 /usr/bin/spyder3
`

Comment: If you have `sudo` permissions in your computer, then fix the executable permissions for `/usr/bin/spyder3` and use Spyder as a regular user. You'll also need to remove `~/.spyder2-py3` with `sudo` so that folder can be used by your regular user.